# How to invoke method which rewrite in sub class using javascript(es5)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-5

I hava two class, one is Base Class called ChartBase, the other is Sub Class called ChartExtend, the code is following:

```
/*Base Class Defined*/
function ChartBase(element, data, settings, type) {
  // do something
  this.init();
};
ChartBase.prototype = {
  init:function(){
    this.initConfig();
    // do other things;
  },
  initConfig:function(){
    this.setBaseConfig();
  },
  setBaseConfig:function(){
    // do something;
  }
}

/*Sub Class Defined*/
function ChartExtend(element, data, settings, type) {
   ChartBase.apply(this, arguments);
};
ChartExtend.prototype = {
  initConfig:function(){
    this.setBaseConfig();
    this.setExternalConfig();
  },
  setExternalConfig:function(){
    // do something;
  }
};

/*Sub Class extend Base Class*/
var TempClass = function() {};　　
TempClass.prototype = ChartBase.prototype;　　
ChartExtend.prototype = new TempClass();　
ChartExtend.prototype.constructor = ChartExtend;
ChartExtend.uber = ChartBase.prototype;

/*instance*/
new ChartExtend(selector, data, settings, 'line');
```

***I found the 'initConfig' method invoked in ChartBase, not the method in ChartExtend when I created an instance, however, the 'this' pointed to ChartExtend in 'init' function.***[image]

**1. Why still call its own prototype method in ChartBase?**

**2. How to invoke the rewrited method in ChartExtend?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You are overwriting your methods defined in `ChartExtend.prototype` when you are doing `ChartExtend.prototype = new TempClass();`. That's why, when you invoke `initConfig` method, it is of `ChartBase` and not of `ChartExtend`.

To correct this, you need to properly inherit the classes so that the Base Class Methods can be overridden by the Sub class method. See the below example.

```js
// Base Class
function ChartBase() {}

// Prototype functions
ChartBase.prototype.initConfig = function() {
  console.log('Base Class :: initConfig');
}
ChartBase.prototype.setBaseConfig = function() {
  console.log('Base Class :: setBaseConfig');
}

// Sub Class
function ChartExtent() {
  ChartBase.apply(this, arguments);
}

// Extend base class
ChartExtent.prototype = new ChartBase()

// Define sub class prototypes
ChartBase.prototype.initConfig = function() {
  console.log('Sub Class :: initConfig');
  this.setBaseConfig();
}

// Create instance 
var instance = new ChartExtent()

// Call instance method
instance.initConfig()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have resolve by myself. The reson is I write wrong code to override Base prototype methods.
using `a.prototyp.b=function(){};
a.prototyp.c=function(){};` instead of
`a.prototyp = {
  b=function(){},
  c=function(){}
};`
What's more, my 'TempClass' is an empty class for inheriting base class prototype methods, which make the base class prototype methods not be changed when I modify the sub class prototype methods